# How to use try/catch with validatepattern using parameters?

Tags: powershell

Basically, I need to be able to enter .'Nameofmyscript.ps1' 80, 80, 80, 90, 100, 100 (for example) in powershell. With these numbers, the script will do something with them. I just need to be able to type them in how I said above.

I am unable to do this without using a parameter, so I was wondering if there's a way to add a parameter in this. Since in my current script, it only accepts the integers I enter in the actual code.

*Also sorry if my powershell language is a bit messed up, I'm pretty new still. Thanks in advance for any help!

What I have so far:

```
try 
    {
    [ValidatePattern("^\d+$")] 
    [int] $G1 = 88
    [int] $G2 = 77
    [int] $G3 = 66
    [int] $G4 = 55
    [int] $G5 = 44
    [int] $G6 = 33
    
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException] {
    [int]$G1 = 10
} catch {
    Write-Host "Please make sure you are only inputting integers."
    Exit
}   

Write-Host $G1 
Write-Host $G2
Write-Host $G3 
Write-Host $G4
Write-Host $G5 
Write-Host $G6
```

Comment: You're looking for a `param` block. It handles parameter validation for you.

Comment: @DanielMann Deleted my previous comment, I understand what you mean, thank you

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking for repeated validation until correct input of all parameters, is that the case?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon hi again! Yes, that's what I'm looking for. As well as an error message if the input is wrong, to try again, etc.

Comment: Ok, as is, a `param(..)` block with 6 `[int]` parameters (`G1` to `G6`) will not accept this syntax: `.\Nameofmyscript.ps1 80, 80, 80, 90, 100, 100`. It will accept this syntax: `.\Nameofmyscript.ps1 80 80 80 90 100 100`. Are you ok with that?

Comment: I'm okay with that, I just am still confused on how to actually get the error checking message. The below reply is very helpful it's just not exactly how I need it to be. I suppose I don't need to use try/catch, but I need to error check it in a way that if a user does not input an integer, an error message will pop up instead of the big red text.

Answer (score 4):

The `[ValidateXXX()]` attribute declaration is used on **parameters** in a `param(..)` block.
What you describe is a script that takes 6 integer parameter values (optional with default values).
Because these are defined as `[int]`, there is no reason to use `[ValidatePattern("^\d+$")]` as if they were **strings**.. after all, an integer is always numeric.

What you could do is `[ValidateRange(min, max)]` to make sure each parameter is within an expected range of values, or `[ValidateScript({..})]` for instance to check if the given value is less than or greater than some value. (for that see the last example parameter `$G6`)

If validation fails an exception is thrown and the script stops there.

Try starting your script with

```
param (
    [ValidateRange(80, 90)]  # this ensures the value of param $G1 must be between 80 and 90 (inclusive)
    [int]$G1 = 88,
    [ValidateRange(70, 80)]  # this ensures the value of param $G2 must be between 70 and 80 (inclusive)
    [int]$G2 = 77,
    [ValidateRange(60, 70)]  # this ensures the value of param $G3 must be between 60 and 70 (inclusive)
    [int]$G3 = 66,
    [ValidateRange(50, 60)]  # this ensures the value of param $G4 must be between 50 and 60 (inclusive)
    [int]$G4 = 55,
    [ValidateRange(40, 50)]  # this ensures the value of param $G5 must be between 40 and 50 (inclusive)
    [int]$G5 = 44,
    [ValidateScript({$_ -lt 40})]  # this ensures the value of param $G6 must less than 40
    [int]$G6 = 33
)

# do something with the values
Write-Host $G1 
Write-Host $G2
Write-Host $G3 
Write-Host $G4
Write-Host $G5 
Write-Host $G6
```

---

If you want your own error message if the validfation fails, you need to use the `ValidateScript` option like:

```
[ValidateScript({
    if ($_ -lt 40) { $true }  # all is well
    else { throw "Value $_ is invalid. You must enter a value less than 40" }
})]
[int]$G6 = 33
```

or when defining the parameter as string where you want to receive an integer value, you could do:

```
[ValidateScript({
    if ($_ -match '^\d+$') { $true }  # all is well
    else { throw "Value $_ is invalid. You must enter digits only" }
})]
[string]$G6
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I'm going to save this code for future use. Would validatepattern also work in this way? 

The only thing is I need it to have an error message if it is NOT an integer, but I totally understand what you mean about the int. Do you know any ways to add an error message to that?

Comment: @RachelD Please see my edit

Comment: @RachelD These are just examples of course. Have a google search on parameter validation. You'll find lost of useful tipe on it, like [this one](https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/29958/parameter-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[validate...]` attributes which will throw and stop the script when a condition is not met, if you're looking to have the user input the parameters until all are integers then this would need to be validated within the script itself.

In this case, this `param(...)` will allow any kind of input and all validation is done in the `begin {...}` block. If an invalid input is found (`-notmatch '^\d+$'`) keep asking for a new input until the pattern matches all digits or the user decides to abort the script.

Lastly, after all validation is done, convert the parameters to `[int]`.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    $G1 = 88,
    $G2 = 77,
    $G3 = 66,
    $G4 = 55,
    $G5 = 44,
    $G6 = 33
)

begin
{
    while($PSBoundParameters.Values -notmatch '^\d+$')
    {
        foreach($key in $PSBoundParameters.Keys)
        {
            if($PSBoundParameters[$key] -notmatch '^\d+$')
            {
                "Invalid input for Parameter '$key'. Only integers are allowed." |
                Write-Warning

                :inner while($true)
                {
                    if(($choice = Read-Host 'Try again? (Y / N)') -notmatch '^y|n$')
                    {
                        continue
                    }

                    switch ($choice)
                    {
                        Y { 
                            $newInput = Read-Host "Provide new input for Parameter '$key'"
                            $PSBoundParameters[$key] = $newInput
                            break inner
                        }
                        N {
                            'Aborting...'
                            exit
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $PSBoundParameters.Keys.ForEach({
        Get-Variable $_ | Set-Variable -Value ([int]$PSBoundParameters[$_])
    })
}

process
{
    # Just for testing
    Get-Variable G* | Select-Object Name, Value, @{
        name = 'IsInt'
        expression = {$_.Value -is [int]}
    }
    
    # Code goes here...
}
```

**Sample Input / Output:**

```
PS /> ./script.ps1 zxc 80 asd 123 45 66

WARNING: Invalid input for Parameter 'G1'. Only integers are allowed.
Try again? (Y / N): y
Provide new input for Parameter 'G1': 123
WARNING: Invalid input for Parameter 'G3'. Only integers are allowed.
Try again? (Y / N): y
Provide new input for Parameter 'G3': 456

Name Value IsInt
---- ----- -----
G1     123  True
G2      80  True
G3     456  True
G4     123  True
G5      45  True
G6      66  True
```